# Is it possible in Drupal 8 to allow registered site users to see each other's email addresses?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-permissions

I'm developing a Drupal 8 website for a small volunteer organization of trusted members. For those who have a certain role on the website, we'd like to use a View to display all of the registered user information (only to other registered users). I have the View working fine, but the email field is only displayed for admin users.

I checked permissions to no avail, and have been reading through various posts for a couple of hours but none seem to answer the question.

Ideally trying to solve this within the CMS, but happy to do PHP if necessary.

[Screenshot of current View output as Admin](https://snag.gy/tGU9Ic.jpg) I'm trying to keep the email field when viewing as a registered, non-admin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a viable patch solution for this issue - thanks to those who wrote it. Patch is just a few lines in two PHP files that creates a new permission options for viewing other users' email addresses.

Patch is below, from [this Drupal post](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2799049).

```
From b0c658e8707f1b851caf700eec9ee4001b6dbbb6 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Axel Rutz <axel.rutz@machbarmacher.net>
Date: Sat, 22 Dec 2018 02:40:28 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] Issue #2799049 by cilefen, axel.rutz: Add new permission to
 view user email field

---
 core/modules/user/src/UserAccessControlHandler.php | 3 +++
 core/modules/user/user.permissions.yml             | 2 ++
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+)

diff --git a/core/modules/user/src/UserAccessControlHandler.php b/core/modules/user/src/UserAccessControlHandler.php
index 9e04c3ffda..486ee744a0 100644
--- a/core/modules/user/src/UserAccessControlHandler.php
+++ b/core/modules/user/src/UserAccessControlHandler.php
@@ -120,6 +120,9 @@ protected function checkFieldAccess($operation, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_
         // Allow view access to own mail address and other personalization
         // settings.
         if ($operation == 'view') {
+          if ($field_definition->getName() === 'mail' && $account->hasPermission('view user mail field')) {
+            return AccessResult::allowed()->cachePerPermissions();
+          }
           return $is_own_account ? AccessResult::allowed()->cachePerUser() : AccessResult::neutral();
         }
         // Anyone that can edit the user can also edit this field.
diff --git a/core/modules/user/user.permissions.yml b/core/modules/user/user.permissions.yml
index a295b1f98f..f21f1deea4 100644
--- a/core/modules/user/user.permissions.yml
+++ b/core/modules/user/user.permissions.yml
@@ -11,6 +11,8 @@ administer users:
   restrict access: true
 access user profiles:
   title: 'View user information'
+view user mail field:
+  title: 'View user mail field'
 change own username:
   title: 'Change own username'
 select account cancellation method:
-- 
2.17.1
```